# Django, Bower. Организация работы с сторонними библиотеками в Django-проекте

Tags: django, bower, организация, project-management

Доброго времени суток! Нужен совет по организации проекта на Django с использованием Bower'a.

Упрощенная структура проекта:

```
src
├── apps
├── base
├── common
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── utils
```

Текущие скрипты хранятся в каталоге

```
common/static/js
```

Где хранить библиотеки, загруженные с помощью bower? (о возможности установки на сервере из манифеста знаю, но их планирую включить в репозиторий)

Разумно изменить каталог по умолчанию в настройках bower с

```
 bower_components/
```

на

```
 common/script/js
```

чтобы все скрипты (внешние и самописные) хранились в одном каталоге? Или такая организация проекта некорректна?

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своими замечаниями и советами по организации структуры проекта

Answer (score 0):

Прошло пару месяцев с моего вопроса, много узнал и постараюсь ответить.

Bower минималистичен и прост в освоении, но для управления сторонними библиотеками [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) предпочтителен, особенно с надстройкой [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) для предотвращения нежелательного обновления пакетов.

Разработчики консолидирутся вокруг npm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эту картинку и более подробный ответ можно увидеть в [ответе](https://www.quora.com/Why-use-Bower-when-there-is-npm) на Quora

Сторонние библиотеки, полученные с помощью нпм, лучше выносить вместе с своими скриптами подальше от бэкенд-кода по своим папкам и сшивать сборщиками, например, webpack.